# JS polyfill CSS child selector to IE6

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-6, css-selectors

I'm looking for a polyfill to add the `>` selector to IE6. I know about Selectivizr, but I don't want to include it all for that one rule. Are there any simple scripts around to do this? I've got jQuery, so that could be included.

Comment: Selectivizr doesn't even mention support for any combinators, so I doubt including that will work at all, oddly enough. One that *does* work and *does* have a big bunch of bloat to go with it is [IE7.js](https://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/)

Comment: You can emulate the child selector using the following set of rules: `parent child {style:value;} parent * child {style:default-value}`.

Comment: take a look at the jquery source how they manage to get the `>` work in ie6. Or you could change your markup, introduce some classes for those child-elements and forget all that stress.

Comment: @Rocket unfortunately, some people work in corporate environments where 25% of the workstations still have IE6 on them

Comment: @Christoph The actual selector engine is [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/), the implementation can be found [at line 425 in the source code](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/blob/master/sizzle.js#L425).

Comment: @Damon: At my job, I had the same issue.  Fortunately, it was IE7.  =(

Comment: @damon or they live in china, where marketshare of IE6 is still by >25%... :-(

Comment: @RobW n1, i read it's sizzle, but forgot the name;)

Answer (score 3):

jQuery will work with the child selector regardless of the browser. So you could use jQuery to manually apply the styles as a class on page load.

`jQuery('parent>child').addClass('parent-child-class');`

Comment: this method can work in certain situations, but it can easily run into the problem of IE6 not supporting multiple classes on a single element

Answer (score 1):

```
.example * {background: #00f; }
.example * * {background: none; }
```

This will have result similar to:

```
.example > * {background: #00f; }
```

But be careful with selectors' specificity.

More usable way is to add extra classes for IE6 via JavaScript/jQuery:

```
$('.example > *').addClass('example-child');
```

Answer (score 0):

The only other polyfill I know of for old IE versions that does this kind of thing is [Dean Edwards' IE7.js library](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/). (and the follow-up libraries ie8.js and ie9.js).

IE7.js is a library that was released way back when IE6 was the current version. It's purpose was to polyfill as much of the functionality available in newer browsers that was missing from IE6 as possible. It was called "IE7.js" as a way of saying "in the absence of a new version being released by Microsoft, this is my attempt to force IE up to modern standards".

IE8.js and IE9.js were released subsequently, shortly after the release of IE7 and IE8 respectively.

IE7.js does include polyfills for a lot of IE6's missing CSS functionality, including the `>` selector.

If you don't want to use Selectivizr, then this is the only other library I know of that does what you want.

Hope that helps.